# Should I use TitanDB?

Tags: neo4j, amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases, titan, janusgraph

I am thinking of using TitanDB. It seems to really fit our needs (we have full control over the storage engine and we can build it on top of DynamoDB). However I am worried about the fact that the project is not maintained anymore and a fork was created, JanusGraph, to continue the project. Is it still safe to use TitanDB? Should I use JanusGraph instead (Is it ready for production and can it be deployed on AWS using DynamoDB)?

Comment: It's been [2700+ days since TitanDB's been updated](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/commit/ee226e52415b8bf43b700afac75fa5b9767993a5). Almost 7.5 years and this is a top JanusGraph-tagged post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you plan on maintaining it by yourself, no, you should not use TitanDB. Titan has not seen updates in almost 2 years. It is far out of date on its core dependencies.

You should use [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org). It was established as a project at the Linux Foundation in January 2017, and 2 releases have already been made. Many individuals and companies are involved in the open community.

If you check out the [AWS Labs DynamoDB Titan Storage adapter](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/tree/master), you'll see that [Alex Patrikalakis](https://github.com/amcp) has already integrated JanusGraph 0.1.1 on the master branch. Alex is also a committer on JanusGraph.

Comment: Thank you, are there any major architectural differences between Titan and JanusGraph?

Comment: No, JanusGraph was forked from the `titan11` branch. One of the initial goals of the project was easy migration for existing Titan users.